# How to call a function present in a different R script from an R executable using Nextflow

Tags: r, nextflow

Let's say I have a Nextflow workflow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

nextflow.enable.dsl=2

process f_to_c {
    input:
    val f
    
    output:
    stdout
    
    script:
    """
    gettemp.R $f
    """
}

workflow {
    Channel.of(80,60) | f_to_c | view
}
```

`gettemp.R` code in `bin` directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

source("lib/farenheit_to_celcius.R")

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
cat(fahrenheit_to_celsius(args[[1]]))
```

With `lib/farenheit_to_celcius.R` contains:

```
fahrenheit_to_celsius <- function(farenheit) {
  return((as.numeric(farenheit) - 32) * 5 / 9)
}
```

When executing the workflow, I get:

```
cannot open file 'lib/farenheit_to_celcius.R': No such file or directory
```

Which I understand why, as Nextflow executes `gettemp.R` within each work directory. But how can I call function in a different R script then? It seems like `source` is not a good option, so a better option might be to create my own library with the functions. However, will it be possible to have Nextflow automatically install/update custom library during execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues that make this nontrivial, but one of them is that R resolves all file paths *relative to the current working directory*. This is generally what you want; *except for source file dependencies*.

`source` fundamentally does not support resolving the path to another source file relative to the currently executing file, and core R has no good way to work around this limitation.

However, if you instead use [‘box’ modules](https://klmr.me/box/) this *does* work.

In your particular case you would change the line

```
source("lib/farenheit_to_celcius.R")
```

to

```
box::use(lib/farenheit_to_celsius[...])
```

(`box::use` is used to declare imports; its comma-separated arguments are package or module specifications, and `[...]` means “attach all exported names of the module”, which approximates what `source` does.)

And to make `lib/farenheit_to_celcius.R` into a module you would add an export declaration above your function:

```
#' @export
fahrenheit_to_celsius <- function(farenheit) {
  return((as.numeric(farenheit) - 32) * 5 / 9)
}
```